# How can I debug a python code that contains Multiprocesses and Multi threads?

Tags: python, debugging, threadpool, process-pool

I am writing a python code that contains the use of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`.
I would like to debug the code, specially the functions that are being called in parallel. Being able to stop execution, set breakpoints, inspect variables etc

How can this be made? I tried but since the processes are being in other threads, breakpoints do not work.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling to search a solution using native debuggers like pdb. I finnally find that maybe using [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with python extension is the best solution, it can automatically step into subprocess/threads.

Comment: which vscode extension specifically?

Comment: The commonly used [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) is enough. No other extension is needed. Just add a break point, it will automatically stop at subprocess / threads